# Is the location of the land of the Houyhnhnms significant?

Tags: setting, jonathan-swift, gullivers-travels

As seen from the below map from the Wikipedia article, which is identical to the version of *Gulliver's Travels* by Jonathan Swift, which I own, the land of the Houyhnhnms is directly below what we now call Australia. Is there any significance to that location? If so, why did he choose that location?
[image: Map from an edition of Gulliver's Travels]